# If the composite function $f_1(f_2(\cdots(f_n(x))\cdots)$ is increasing and $r$ number of $f_i$s are decreasing while rest are increasing...

Tags: calculus, functions

If the composite function $f_1(f_2(f_3(\cdots(f_n(x))\cdots)$ is an increasing function and if $r$ number of functions are decreasing functions while the rest are increasing, find the maximum value of $r(n-r)$ when $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd.

***Attempt:***

I found out that if

$f$ is increasing and $g$ is increasing, $f(g(x))$ is increasing

$f$ is decreasing and $g$ is decreasing, $f(g(x))$ is increasing

$f$ is decreasing and $g$ is increasing, $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ is decreasing.

Let $n$ be even. By taking a function $a(b(c(d(e(f(x))))))$, I found that there has to be even number of increasing functions. But max value is when $r=\frac{n}{2}$ and maximum is $\frac{n^2}{4}$ when $n$ is even. Is this approach correct? Is there a simpler or better method?

Comment: There has to be an even number of decreasing functions, not increasing functions. Other than that, you are correct.

Comment: Is there no other method other than considering some function? Its like a trivial solution.

Comment: You mean you noticed this by examining particular functions? I thought you meant that you had figured out in general that composing two increasing or two decreasing functions gives an increasing function, and that composing any increasing and decreasing functions gives decreasing.

Comment: when $n$ is odd, the number of increasing functions must be odd?

Comment: Yes. The number of decreasing functions has to be even, regardless of $n$. This is because, starting at the inside and working out, every time to add in a new decreasing function, the overall composition switches direction. So you start out increasing ($f(x) = x$ is increasing), then the first decreasing function switches it to decreasing, then the 2nd one switches it back to increasing again, and so on. To be increasing, the decreasing count has to be even. The increasing count is whatever is left over.